# Difference between InstallSchema and InstallData

Tags: magento2, database, installdata

I want to know the difference between InstallSchema and InstallData in details.

I also need to know when can I use `InstallSchema.php` and `InstallData.php`?

Comment: Let me know if you still have any issue , otherwise accept answer so other user gets helped

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**First both InstallSchema And InstallData both method are called when you install any new module**

> Schema setup scripts change database schema, they create or change
>   needed database tables. 
>       If module is installing, Setup\InstallSchema::install() is executed.

**It means it create new table and its fields with its structure.**

> InstallData setup scripts contain entries module needs to insert into
>   database. 
>       Attributes that come with Magento by default,Cms pages, various default groups and roles, are all examples of data setup.

**Data setup is executed after Schema setup, they function in a similar fashion.**

> **So come to the conclustion, Main difference between both is InstallSchema is used to make table and its structure. While
>   InstallData is used to insert/add data into table.**

Comment: Means,InstallData use for add attribute for `Customer`,`Qoute`,`Order`,`Catalog`,`Product`,`Category`.

Comment: Well you partially correct  , InstallData is used to InsertData of attribute (value of attribute) Lets say you have created table called "Slider" by installSchema Now you need to insert each slide Data then you need to use InstallData file and define data of each slide . Make sense ?

Answer (score 9):

**Magento2** uses **Four Type** of files for the Initial operations related to database that are executed just with the installation process of module (These files runs only once through out of their existence). Those files are as follows

> 1. InstallSchema.php
> 2. InstallData.php
> 3. UpgradeSchema.php
> 4. UpgradeData.php

All of these files are present ate `Magento_root/{app/Vendor}/{Vendor_Name}/{Module_Name}/Setup` Name space of your magento module. Here I have described all the files with their use.

**InstallSchema.php**

> This file is executed first just after your modules registration
>   (Means just after your module & its version entries are done in to the
>   table -> `setup_module`). This file is used to create tables with
>   their columns attribute into your database that are later used by the
>   new installed module.

**InstallData.php**

> This file is executed after `InstallSchema.php`. It is used to add
>   data to the newly created table or any existing table.

**UpgradeSchema.php**

> This file comes with the module & runs only then, if you are already
>   having that modules previous version installed in your magento(Means
>   it has entry of its previous version into the table ->
>   `setup_module`). It is used to manipulate the table related to the
>   module(Means it is used to alter the table schema means columns
>   attribute & to add new column into that table).

**UpgradeData.php**

> This file runs after `UpgradeSchema.php`. It is having the same
>   concept as **`InstallData.php`** has but using this file you can
>   change/alter the database contents without the use of model files. You
>   can also use this file to add new content to the database same us
>   **`InstallData.php`**. But same like **`UpgradeSchema.php`** it will also runs only then if you are having that modules previous version
>   installed in your magento.

As I said in starting these files runs only once so the basic use of this files is to prepare the tables & data for the Module which is been get used by the module through out its existence.

> Note: Magento uses these files to create tables that are used into
>   Magentos functionalities & to add the contents like cms_contents,
>   customer_groups & attributes, Products_Types & attributes, Taxation
>   groups etc.

Answer (score 8):

There are following difference,

**InstallSchema**

> InstallSchema.php purpose is to create new table/attribute/fields in
>   Database

**InstallData**

> InstallData.php purpose is to insert Data/value into database.

Answer (score 4):

There is basic difference between 2 is

`InstallSchema` will run when the module is installed to setup the database structure

While `InstallData` will run when the module is installed to initial the data for database table

Hoope this clear your query.