# Set default values in Install Schema

Tags: magento2, database

I want to create a table with one default row.

i.e. I have two attributes. How to create table with (1,1) entry by default using Install Schema?

Answer (score 3):

In addition to Dave's answer which use InstallData.php, we could use **InstallSchema.php** too, which is **more simple** and codes like below, notice the `'default' => 1` in `addColumn` method.

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallSchemaInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table;

class InstallSchema implements InstallSchemaInterface
{

    public function install(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $installer = $setup;
        $installer->startSetup();

        try {
            $table = $installer->getConnection()->newTable(
                $installer->getTable('table_name')
            )
                ->addColumn(
                    'number',
                    Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
                    null,
                    ['nullable' => false, 'unsigned' => true, 'default' => 1]
                )
                ->addColumn(
                    'number_2',
                    Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
                    null,
                    ['default' => 1]
                )
            ;

            $installer->getConnection()->createTable($table);
        } catch (\Zend_Db_Exception $e) {
        }

        $installer->endSetup();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want add default data in your table like first row , You need to create **InstallData.php** file in your setup folder

**Try below code :**

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Magento\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface {


    /**
     * 
     * Install Data in custom table
     *   
     */
    public function install( ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context ) {
        $setup->startSetup();

        $tableName = $setup->getTable('your_table_name');

        if ($setup->getConnection()->isTableExists($tableName) == true) {
        $tabledata = [
        [
            'Id' => 1,
            'Code' => 1,

        ]
        ];
        foreach ($tabledata as $data) {
                $setup->getConnection()->insert($tableName, $data);
            } 
        }
         $setup->endSetup();
    }
}
```

**Note :** Basically installschema is used for creating the table structure while installdata is used for add data in that created table.

Refer to know difference between both - [Difference between InstallSchema and InstallData](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/179119/difference-between-installschema-and-installdata)

At the end don't forgot to run **php bin/magento setup:upgrade** command.

Answer (score 0):

Write a InstallData in your setup folder

```
 use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
    use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
    use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

    class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
    {

        public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
        {
            $setup->startSetup();

            $attribute_name= [
                [
                    'attributes_id' => 1,
                    'code' => '1',               
                ],

            ];

            $setup->getConnection()->insertMultiple($setup->getTable('your_tablename'), $attribute_name);

            $setup->endSetup();
        }
    }
```

run `set:up` it will insert default table

Answer (score 0):

> Write Like this

```
$columns = [
                'cartcheck' => [
                    'type' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
                    'nullable' => true,
                    ['default' => '0'],
                    'comment' => 'Cart Checkbox',
                ],
            ];
```

I Hope You Get The Correct Answer