# Differences between InstallSchema and UpgradeSchema?

Tags: discussion, magento2

Do you know what is the design criteria of splitting `InstallSchema` and `UpgradeSchema`? They are basically doing the same thing. It seems redundant to me.

**EDIT 1:** I don't think this is duplicate. I just would like to understand and discuss what is the point of splitting Install and Upgrade scripts.

Anyway, I believe Magento also thinks that this is not a good implementation and decide to change the upgrade system. You can get more information on in [this link](https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-DevBlog/A-Declarative-Approach-for-Database-Schema-Upgrades/ba-p/70763).

Comment: Look like same question https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/179119/difference-between-installschema-and-installdata

Comment: Looks like similar, but not the same. What I would like to know is why they are splitted, InstallSchema and UpgradeShema.

Comment: If you want to edit a table in your module..you cannot use installschema again because the version of Module set already...You can modify table using UpgradeSchema only....By increasing the version of your module in Upgradeschema name and adding version in config file to run your Upgradeschema ...