# Magento Custom Customer Attribute Issue

Tags: magento2, database, customer-attribute, magento2.2.3

I am trying to create a custom attribute for customer but with no success. I am using Magento CE 2.2.3.

Below are the steps I am using

**Step 1**

- Create a Vendor\Module\Setup under add\code
- Create InstallData.php under \Setup folder

Use the following code in InstallData.php

```
<?php
/**
 * @author      Sashas
 * @category    Sashas
 * @package     Sashas_CustomerAttribute
 * @copyright   Copyright (c) 2015 Sashas IT Support Inc. (http://www.extensions.sashas.org) 
 */
namespace Vendor\Module\Setup;
use Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Set as AttributeSet;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\SetFactory as AttributeSetFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

/**
 * @codeCoverageIgnore
 */
class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{

    /**
     * @var CustomerSetupFactory
     */
    protected $customerSetupFactory;

    /**
     * @var AttributeSetFactory
     */
    private $attributeSetFactory;

    /**
     * @param CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory
     * @param AttributeSetFactory $attributeSetFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory,
        AttributeSetFactory $attributeSetFactory
    ) {
        $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
        $this->attributeSetFactory = $attributeSetFactory;
    }


    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {

        /** @var CustomerSetup $customerSetup */
        $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        $customerEntity = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getEntityType('customer');
        $attributeSetId = $customerEntity->getDefaultAttributeSetId();

        /** @var $attributeSet AttributeSet */
        $attributeSet = $this->attributeSetFactory->create();
        $attributeGroupId = $attributeSet->getDefaultGroupId($attributeSetId);

        $customerSetup->addAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'magento_username', [
            'type' => 'varchar',
            'label' => 'Magento Username',
            'input' => 'text',
            'required' => false,
            'visible' => true,
            'user_defined' => true,
            'sort_order' => 1000,
            'position' => 1000,
            'system' => 0,
        ]);

        $attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'magento_username')
        ->addData([
            'attribute_set_id' => $attributeSetId,
            'attribute_group_id' => $attributeGroupId,
            'used_in_forms' => ['adminhtml_customer'],
        ]);

        $attribute->save();


    }
}
```

I also tried to use the following code to create a Select field with Yes/No without any success

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Setup;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{

private $eavSetupFactory;

/**
* Init
*
* @param EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory
*/
public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory)
{
    $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
}

public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
{
            /** @var EavSetup $eavSetup */
            $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
            /**
            * Add attributes to the eav/attribute
            */

            $eavSetup->addAttribute(
                \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
                'tax_custom_attribute',
                [
                    'group' => 'General',
                    'type' => 'int',
                    'backend' => '',
                    'frontend' => '',
                    'label' => 'Taxable or Non-taxable',
                    'input' => 'boolean',
                    'class' => 'tax-nontax-field',
                    'source' => 'Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Boolean',
                    'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
                    'visible' => true,
                    'required' => true,
                    'user_defined' => false,
                    'default' => '1',
                    'searchable' => false,
                    'filterable' => false,
                    'comparable' => false,
                    'visible_on_front' => false,
                    'used_in_product_listing' => false,
                    'unique' => false,
                    'apply_to' => 'simple,configurable,virtual,bundle,downloadable'
                ]
            );



    }
}
```

**Step 2**

- Create registration.php
- Create module.xml

Module is visible when I run the command php bin/magento module:status

Also, I've run the following command after uploading the files
php bin/magento setup:upgrade

**Help Needed**

I basically want to create a customer attribute with a select field which has Yes/No options and then display a downloadable link to PDF forms on customer registration page. The links will only be visible based on Yes/No Selection from the custom field I am trying to create.

Answer (score 0):

Use `UpgradeData.php` instead of `InstallData` more information [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/179119/48355)

> app/code/Vendor/Module/Setup/UpgradeData.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Setup;

use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;
use Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetup;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

class UpgradeData implements  UpgradeDataInterface
{
    private $customerSetupFactory;

    public function __construct(\Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory)
    {
        $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
    }
    public function upgrade(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context){
        $setup->startSetup();

        if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.0.1', '<')) {

            $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
            $customerSetup->addAttribute(
                Customer::ENTITY,
                'Taxable or Non-taxable',
                [
                    'type' => 'int',
                    'label' => 'Taxable or Non-taxable',
                    'input' => 'select',
                    'source' => 'Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Table',
                    'required' => true,
                    'default' => '0',
                    'sort_order' => 160,
                    'system' => false,
                    'position' => 160,
                    'adminhtml_only' => 1,
                    'option' =>
                        array (
                            'values' =>
                                array (
                                    0 => 'No',
                                    1 => 'Yes',
                                ),
                        ),
                ]
            );
            $myAttribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'Taxable or Non-taxable');

            // more used_in_forms ['adminhtml_checkout','adminhtml_customer','adminhtml_customer_address','customer_account_edit','customer_address_edit','customer_register_address']
            $myAttribute->setData(
                'used_in_forms', ['adminhtml_customer', 'customer_account_create', 'customer_account_edit']);
            $myAttribute->save();

        }


        $setup->endSetup();
    }
}
```

**Note:**

1. You can also use `'source' => 'Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Boolean'` instead of `'source' => 'Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Table'` without the custom options `'option' =>...`
2. Check well your module version `version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.0.1', '<')`