# Insert multiple records to multiple custom tables through install script in magento2

Tags: magento2, setup-script, installdata

I have created multiple table schema using setup script like below.

**Setup/InstallSchema.php**

```
   namespace Vendor\Module\Setup;
   use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallSchemaInterface;
   use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
   use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;

 class InstallSchema implements InstallSchemaInterface
{

  public function install(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, 
   ModuleContextInterface $context)
  {
    /**
     * Create table 'tbl_test1'
     */
    $table = $setup->getConnection()
        ->newTable($setup->getTable('tbl_test1'))
        ->addColumn(
            'id',
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
            null,
            ['identity' => true, 'unsigned' => true, 'nullable' => false, 'primary' => true],
            'Pod ID'
        )
        ->addColumn(
            'name',
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
            255,
            ['nullable' => false, 'default' => ''],
            'name'
        );
    $setup->getConnection()->createTable($table);

   /**
     * Create table 'tbl_test_2'
     */
    $table = $setup->getConnection()
        ->newTable($setup->getTable('tbl_test_2'))
        ->addColumn(
            'id',
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
            null,
            ['identity' => true, 'unsigned' => true, 'nullable' => false, 'primary' => true],
            ''
        )
        ->addColumn(
            'mage_order_id',
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
            255,
            ['nullable' => false, 'default' => ''],
            'magento orderid'
        );
    $setup->getConnection()->createTable($table);
```

I need to insert multiple records for each table.

How this can be achieved using installer. Can anyone look into this and update me your answer please.

Comment: You wanna to insert records into your table ??

Comment: @PrathapGunasekaran, yes I have created 2 tables, need to insert multiple records for each table

Comment: For adding data to the tables you required installData or UpgradeData please [follow this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/179119/difference-between-installschema-and-installdata/234918#234918)

Comment: @ABHISHEKTRIPATHI, can you update me InstallData.php code for my tables just with sample data please

Comment: I think you should try with default Magento way
https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/720667eabe94c0a6fdce342f281e597d3dd4f14a/app/code/Magento/Cms/Setup/InstallData.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an **`InstallData script`**
Try this:

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $setup->startSetup();

       $tableName = $setup->getTable('tbl_test1');
       $tableName2 = $setup->getTable('tbl_test_2');

        $data = [
            [
            'id' => NULL,
            'frameName' => 'black box'
            ],
            [
            'id' => NULL,
            'frameName' => 'white box'
            ]
        ];

        $data2 = [
            [
            'id' => NULL,
            'mage_order_id' => 'mage order id1'
            ],
            [
            'id' => NULL,
            'mage_order_id' => 'mage order id2'
            ]
        ];

        foreach($data as $item){
            $setup->getConnection()->insert($tableName,$item);
        }

        foreach($data2 as $item2){
            $setup->getConnection()->insert($tableName2,$item2);
        }

        $setup->endSetup();
    }
}
```

Note: Although **`id`** is defined as `nullable=false` you can still put value for **`id`** as NULL if it defined as `primary key` and `autoincrement` value.
Please Note also, that **InstallData script** only works on the first install of your module, so better uninstall and remove first the module on your **setup_module** table to make it work.

Comment: hi @magefrms, I need to insert 5 to 10 record for each table, need to define all of them?

Comment: I will update answer

Comment: you can do it like above

Comment: okay update me whenever you will encounter an error

Comment: I have updated my answer with an important note

Comment: okay sure, let me prepare file and check it, i have 20 rows for each tables

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91849/discussion-between-jafar-pinjar-and-magefms).

Comment: above code inserted only first record to the respective tables, skipped remaining entries